# How to run AJAX loaded page scripts after loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page like this that page1.php codes will load with ajax in that:

```
...
<div id="myContent" >
<!-- ajax content load here -->
</div>
...
```

and my ajax codes are:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'codes/page.php',
        async: false,
        data: formDatas
        , success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML = response; // response contains page1.php codes
            }
        }
    });
```

and these datas will load from page1.php:

```
<script>
    alert("hello");
</script>

<div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now my problem is that when I load page1.php directly, this alerts "hello". But when I load this contents via ajax , scripts not works and nothing alerted

How do I do to running these scripts after loading datas in **myContent** div.

**thank you all**

Comment: thank you but no. I want to execute scripts that are in page1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra closing bracket in there that's likely causing an error (right beneath the `document.getElementById`).  Also, since you're using jQuery, it's better to use the jQuery selector syntax and html function.

Try this instead of your current code...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'codes/page.php',
    async: false,
    data: formDatas,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#myContent').html(response); //response contains page1.php codes
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For browsers that follow the HTML5 spec (i.e. all current, major browsers), [script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

However, if you use jQuery's [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, your scripts will execute:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'codes/page.php',
    data: formDatas, 
    success: function (response) {
        $('#myContent').html(response);
    }
});
```

**Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhxc5LL4/)**